# Excel weighted completion of tasks

Tags: excel

I have a series of tasks in excel and a list of participants. I wanted to average the completion of the weighted tasks for each user based on checking off the task in excel.

[image: Example]

Comment: So expected output would be a % complete based on the task weights? So for example User 1's score should be 40%, is that right?

Comment: yes thats is correct %

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided sample data, use this array formula in cell Q2 and copy down.  Make sure to confirm the formula as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter.

```
=SUM(($F2:$P2="x")*TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$12))/SUM($C$2:$C$12)
```